# Adding zeroes to a string while scanning C programming

Tags: c, string

I am trying to scan a number , for example the number : 1 and I want to scan it like 0001 in order to do strcat later , that means this number is saved as a string.

Do you know how to add those zeroes in front of the number while I am doing the scanf ?

Thank you for reading , hope to get an answer soon. :)

Comment: The input is 0001 and you want to preserve it, or the input is 1 and you want to store it as 0001?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sprintf` right after `scanf` to create a string that has the leading zeros.

```
char buffer[20];
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
sprintf(buffer, "%04d", n);
```

`buffer` now has `0`s padded at the front.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you're asking, but scanning a number with `scanf` gives you a number, not a string, so prefixing 0s makes no sense.

If you later want to convert that number to a string with leading 0s, you can do that with `sprintf`:

```
sprintf(buffer, "%04d", n);
```

will convert the number `n` into a string in the buffer, with leading 0s added to make it at least 4 digits.

Answer (score 0):

The `scanf` function will ignore leading zeros. But you can format the number as a string after input like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char num[20];
    scanf("%d", &i);
    sprintf(num, "%04d", i);
    printf("%s\n", num);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scan a number that should contain leading zeros then you have to read it as a string and manually enter as 0001.

To verify that the it is an integer with leading zeros, you can use [strtol](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol)
. Then just check if the first character in the string is a '0'.

Thanks , hope it helps